# In css, How do you display an image that is hidden when you hover over a visibe image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have to make an image appear in the right hand corner over the mouse image once my mouse cursor reaches the piece of cheese showing on the screen. I have the code for the image to appear over the mouse image, which I used display: none to hide. What should I do to make the image appear over the mouse image, once I have reached the piece of cheese in the top left corner with the cursor? I think I should be able to use the hover property, but I am not sure how to achieve my goal with it. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

```css
<style>
#myCanvas { border: #333 10px solid;
   position: relative; 
   }

body { padding: 50px; }

#cheese { position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
#mouse { position: absolute;
   padding-top: 390px; 
   padding-left: 520px; 
   }

#line { position: absolute;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-top: 90px;
    }
    
#text1 { position: absolute;
  padding-top: 450px;
  padding-left: 130px;
 }
 
#text2 { position: absolute;
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-left: 110px;
 }

#img { position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    padding-top: 390px; 
    padding-left: 525px;
 }

</style>
```

```html
<body>
<p>
<div id="cheese">
<img src="cheese 2.jpg" alt="cheese" width="120" height="120">
</div>
</p>
<div id="mouse">
<img src="ballet mouse.jpg" alt="Angelina Ballerina" width="190" height="220">
</div>
<div id="line">
<img src="316151-200.png" alt="Pathway" width="480" height="350">
</div>
<div id="text1">
<img src="help.png" alt="text" width="350" height="50">
</div>
<div id="text2">
<img src="find.png" alt="text" width="400" height="55">
</div>
<div id="img">
<a href="#"><img src="MouseEventImg.jpg" alt="Celebrate!" width="190" height="220">
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700px" height="600px"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);
var mouseX = 670;
var mouseY = 570;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);

function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
}

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fillStyle = "#eab4e4";
  context.fill();
 
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();

//make mouse position values accurate
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
 
  while (el) {
 if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
  //deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and pg scroll
  var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  
  xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
  yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
 } else {
  //for all other non-BODY elements
  xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
  yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
 }
 
 el = el.offsetParent;
 }
 return {
  x: xPos,
  y: yPos
 };
}  

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, this is a simple way to achieve this:

Make some container with cheese:

```
<div class='something'>
  <div class='some-cheese'></div>
</div>
```

If you hover over that container, show the cheese:

```
.something {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.something .some-cheese {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FF0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.something:hover .some-cheese {
  opacity: 1;
}
```